# Overlapping condition for case-when

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following query:

```
SELECT case     
 when tbl.id % 2 = 0 then 'mod-2'
 when tbl.id % 3 = 0 then 'mod-3'
 when tbl.id % 5 = 0 then 'mod-5'
 else 'mod-x'
 end as odds, tbl.id from some_xyz_table tbl;
```

If the table has Id `5,6,7` then it is returning output as (copied from pg-admin):

```
"mod-5";5
"mod-2";6
"mod-x";7
```

But, here I can see `6` is divisible by both `2` and `3`. And my expected output is:

```
"mod-5";5
"mod-2";6
"mod-3";6   <-- this
"mod-x";7
```

Is there any way to modify this query to obtain such output? Any alternate solution will do for me.

Comment: So you want to get 4 rows from a table that only contains three rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. Not sure if its possible or not. Just trying my luck here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with UNION queries [EDIT changed it to use UNION ALL]:

```
SELECT 'mod-5', id FROM tbl -- divisible by 5
WHERE id %5 = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mod-2', id FROM tbl -- divisible by 2
WHERE id %2 = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mod-3', id FROM tbl -- divisible by 3
WHERE id %3 = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mod-x',id FROM tbl  -- not divisible by 5,3 or 2
WHERE id %5 <> 0 AND id%2 <> 0 AND id % 3 <> 0
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Well there won't be duplicates - is it because union all is more efficient? Changed, anyway...